# Makefile phony "clean" target executes the include directive

Tags: gnu-make

I highlight the relevant parts in of my Makefile here:

```
...
$(DEP_FILES): dep/%.d: src/%.cc
        some command

include $(DEP_FILES)

    
.PHONY: clean

clean:
        ...
```

when I run `make clean` the `include` directive is executed which executes the rules in the dependency `.d` files.

This generates errors if there are errors in the dependency files.

Why is the `include` directive executed when calling `make clean`?

`clean` should only be for cleaning. How to avoid this situation?

Comment: How would `make` know that there are no `clean:` targets in the files included by `include` without actually including them?

Comment: @they, is it possible to tell `make` that that there are no `clean` rules in the included files so that he skips the `include` directive?

Comment: Did you try moving the `include` directive beneath the `clean:` target? I'm not writing an answer to this as I'm not really a GNU `make` user (and I don't even know if it's GNU `make` you're using).

Comment: @they Following a quick test your suggestion works.

Comment: GNU Make tries to re-make any included file if necessary, which I think is what is causing your problems. I don’t have a fix off-hand; the usual trick to disable re-making Makefiles isn’t appropriate here.

Comment: You can't avoid that situation. A makefile is NOT a shell script. The whole makefile (and all its includes) is fully parsed and its whole dependency graph is built BEFORE any action is taken. tl;dr; you should fix the errors in the dependency files. You could refactor the Makefile into a main one and one (or more) called recursively via `$(MAKE) -f`, but there's no "recipe" for that.